# Multiple ParseServer instances on Heroku and MongoLab

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

As Parse is winding down its hosted services by Jan 2017, I am slowly working on migrating my current applications from Parse.com to Heroku hosted services and MongoLab.

I have multiple applications under my account currently hosted on Parse.com. They have basically the same data schema and Cloud codes, so that one application is able to share data across other applications.

To call a cloud function on any application, I only need to call, e.g.,

```
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/{FUNCTION1}
```

with passed APP_ID and MASTER_KEY to differentiate applications.

However, if I go ahead to migrate my applications to Heroku, each application would have a unique app name, e.g.,

```
https://{APP1}.herokuapp.com
```

Then the cloud function on one application would look like:

```
https://{APP1}.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/{FUNCTION1}
```

so the same cloud function on other app would look like:

```
https://{APP2}.herokuapp.com/parse/functions/{FUNCTION1}
```

My question is: is there a way to organize my applications the way Parse.com does currently so that the domain name in each cloud function URL is the same across different applications?

Comment: To further clarify my question:
With any Parse.com user running multiple hosted applications under the user account like me, does one need to create multiple Heroku applications, each connected to an individual MongoDB database?

Comment: I can't speak to the application part (I imagine this would require some tweaking of the Parse Server code) but you can connect all your applications to one MongoDB database if you'd like. You just need to set your databaseUri to the same URI across all the databases and that should hook your Parse app to the database. You can also email support@mongolab.com if you have any questions about this.

Comment: Did you achieve using one Heroku instance for multiple Parse Servers?